# How to update block in magento using ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, sidebar

i want to update sidebar block in magento 1.9 when add to cart action fire

my controller is

```
public function sidebarAction()
{
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_sidebar')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml')->toHtml();
}
```

But this code cant update block

Comment: please show your cart sidebar code? which default is call in pages. and want it xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1:Create new event handler for this action
so, create local.xml in (`app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtemplate/layout`) and put this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <yourRouter_controller_sidebar>
    </yourRouter_controller_sidebar>
</layout>
```

and in `sidebarAction` add below code:

```
 $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
$layout->removeOutputBlock('root');
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
$page = $layout->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
$container = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'amit');
$container->setData('page',$page->toHtml());
$layout->addOutputBlock('amit_json', 'toJson');
```

**Note:**  cart_sidebar is your cart siderbar block name which is defined at `checkout.xml` in `default` theme.

For Rwd theme call cart sidebar from head using below code

```
<block type="checkout/cart_minicart" name="minicart_head" template="checkout/cart/minicart.phtml" before="-">.....
```

and here block name is minicart_head. So you should make required change.

```
$layout->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
```

to

```
$layout->getBlock('minicart_head');
```

Answer (score 4):

your ajax action tag in config.xml should content like below

```
 <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar_ajax" as="cart_sidebar_ajax" template="checkout/cart/ajaxsidebar.phtml">
                    <action method="addItemRender">
                        <type>simple</type>
                        <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block>
                        <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addItemRender">
                        <type>grouped</type>
                        <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block>
                        <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                    <action method="addItemRender">
                        <type>configurable</type>
                        <block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block>
                        <template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                </block>
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: can u explain how it's works and where can i add this code

Comment: If you've created a custom module and controller that outputs an AJAX response already, you just need to make sure the block has the correct type, template, and actions set. This worked for me.

Comment: @Justin, glad to help you.